# Transmitting Data Between Websites Via The Internet

Tags: json, web-development-server

I've edited this question. I hope this version is a bit more clear.

I am seeking to have a programmer build a process for me.   I need to ensure what is recommended is a best practice for the below process.

Here are the steps I need to have built:

1. Have a https: webform on my server that submits client inputted data into a database on my server. The data is personal identifiable information and needs to be securely transmitted in the next step.
2. Once the data is loaded in my database, I need to transfer the data in an encrypted/Json format to a third-party server.  The third-party will unencrypt the data, score it and send it back to my server encrypted.
3. While the data is being sent and scored by the third-party, the client will see a browser screen indicating processing...
4. Once the data is scored and sent back to my server, it will be unencrypted and it will update the client's browser with options based on the score given by the third-party.

Based on what I understand, I think an API on both my server and the third-party server might be best.

What is the best practice approach for the above process?

Below are some questions I have which would be very helpful for me to understand in your response.

1. Is the API approach the best?
2. What process is used by the third-party to unencrypt data I send and vice versa?  How do I prevent others from unencrypting the data if it is intercepted?

3)While the data is being scored by the third-party, the client browser will show processing.  From a web development standpoint how does this work?  Also, from a web development standpoint, how exactly is the processing screen triggered to update with results on the client's browser screen when the data is sent back from the third-party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that you will be transmitting, as you mentioned is `encrypted` so it will totally depend on the `encryption algorithm` you are using, generally encrypted data are stored as `BASE64` or `HEX` so after encryption the data will be passed in the above-mentioned format.

To answer you second question on "how will the receiving website receive the file?", there are several ways you can do this:

1. You can share the backend database your website is using then it will just be a simple query away (by shared I mean both the websites use the same database).
2. Another way of achieving this is to use an API which can store your data and can be globally used in any application it is called at
3. Or you can set up a simple php server locally at your machine and send data between websites using the `HTTP: GET` or `HTTP: POST` requests.

also avoid using un-necessary tags like `web-development-server` or `data-transfer` or `transmission` etc. these tags are useless and unrelated to your question. You should only tag those which are related to your question, a simple tag for `web-development` would be enough.

also edit out your question to make us properly understand, what problems you are facing? what have you tried? what do you expect from us in the answer?

please clarify your question more.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply.  I edited to be more clear about what I am trying to understand and solve.

Comment: @user1609391 thank you very much for editing the question now I can clearly understand what you want. And to answer your question you can go for an `API` approach it will be easy to do so try the approach using a mock `API` and `Server` using `Postman`: [link](https://www.postman.com), here you can make your own `Mock Server` and `API` for `FREE` and use it in development of your project, I hope my answer was useful to you best wishes

Answer (score 1):

Your concept of files being sent around is kind of wrong, because in most cases none of this is ever been written to disk, and so there is no JSON file with a file-name - and these are not directly being encrypted, but only pushed through an encrypted channel. Most commonly both sides either use HTTPS or WSS as the protocol, which encrypts / decrypts the data being exchanged transparently (all by itself). And depending on the protocol which is being used, this requires either a combination of client & server, server & server - or a P2P network - to be installed.

Further reading: [Internetworking Basics - Computer and Information Science](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/%7Esklar/teaching/f05/cis3.2/notes/cisco-introint.pdf).